# Remove Image Opacity Inside Container with Opacity

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove image opacity when the image is placed in a container which has `opacity: 0.6;`?

I need the contained image to have no opacity within a background that has opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is inherited and can't be overridden, however, there are a couple of ways of achieving a similar effect:

1. You could use something other than opacity, such as rgba. Here the background is red with an opacity set as 0.6 with the following declaration: `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);` [Support is IE9+ (and all the proper browsers)](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba) - so unless you have a need to support old IE's then you'll be OK
2. You could separate the elements so the internal element is not a child of the parent and use negative margins or position values to drag the internal element into position. This is useful is the background itself is an image, or more complex than a flat colour.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1s584hsw/1/) demonstrates both solutions. You can see how there's no need to set any opacity for example one, as the `rgba` declaration covers that, and the second, the `.image` is not in the `.background` so the opacity has no effect.

NB: The example of positioning with negative values uses left: -75px as the float declaration makes all the elements appear on a line where there's space, so the element to overlay appears to the left of the element it overlays. You would want to apply more constraint in a real-world example - as you'd want to guarantee the element being dragged appears where you expect it to before dragging.

Finally, if the background of the parent element is an image, you could process it in PhotoShop or similar image editing package, or server side if its a user generated image, in order to apply the opacity directly to the image.